# Displaying a block on mouseover inline

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display a `<div>` block when mouse enters an element

My code so far:

```
<div class="dropdown">

    <a href="#men" onmouseover ="ddmenin()" onmouseout="ddmenout()">MEN</a>

    <div class="dropdowncontent" id="ddmen" style="margin-left:100px;"> 

        <a href="#topwear"> TOPWEAR&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a><br/>
        <a href="#bottomwear"> BOTTOMWEAR </a></br>
        <a href="#footwear"> FOOTWEAR &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>

    </div> 

</div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var ddm=document.getElementById("ddmen")

function ddmenin()
{
    ddm.style.display="block";
}

function ddmenout()
{
    ddm.style.display="none";
}
```

But when i hover over `<a href="#men">` I cannot click on the links in the `<div>` with `class="dropdowncontent"` as the block disappears when i leave the  `<a href="#men">`

I don't understand why this is happening since i have used onmouseover, which is valid even for child elements.

I have tried doing it using css but for some reason the following does not work (Style.css is used in above html)

```
STYLE.CSS

.dropdowncontent{
    display:none; 
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdowncontent{display:block;}
```

Can someone please correct my code to satisfy my needs or has any other simple alternative?

Comment: Use CSS, there is no reason to use JavaScript

Comment: bind the event to the parent element  dropdown, not the anchor.

Comment: @epascarello as i said, the css code i mentioned in the question does not seem to give any effect

Comment: Use either js or css only to get the desire effect. Css code is working fine for me https://jsbin.com/merufimejo/edit?html,console,output

Comment: `</br>` You have a typo with a tag and your css is working so my guess something else is wrong if that CSS is not working. Maybe you should show us more code/css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` in your `<div class="dropdown">` instead. Because, when you go to the `div.dropdowncontent` you probably invokes the `onmouseout` event. So the code will be like this:

```html
    <div class="dropdown" onmouseover="ddmenin()" onmouseout="ddmenout()">

        <a href="#men">MEN</a>

        <div class="dropdowncontent" id="ddmen" style="margin-left:100px;"> 

            <a href="#topwear"> TOPWEAR&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a><br/>
            <a href="#bottomwear"> BOTTOMWEAR </a></br>
            <a href="#footwear"> FOOTWEAR &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>

        </div> 

    </div>
```

See if it works ;D

Comment: If this does not work and the CSS does not work, then you are not giving us the correct HTML/CSS code.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your `div` link container is not part of `a` link, so when you move cursor to dropdown menu you leave the link and `onmouseout` listener does its job.

What you want is to hide the menu when it's not needed anymore. E.g. you clicked on the menu item or you left the menu and didn't return for some time.

To achieve this you can do the following:

- Add hiding the menu to `click` listener on menu items
- Add a function that starts some timer as soon as you leave the dropdown button or the menu (so that makes two `onmouseout` listeners). If you return there, you can reset the timer in `onmouseover`. When timer is done you can hide the menu.

It can look like this:

```js
const $ = document.querySelector;
let menuTimeoutId;
const menu = $('#ddmen');

function stopMenuTimeoutAndShowMenu() { 
    if (menuTimeoutId) {
        clearTimeout(menuTimeoutId);
        menuTimeoutId = null;
    }
     menu.style.display = 'block';
}

function startMenuTimeout() {
    window.menuTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        menu.style.display = 'none';
    }, 2000); // possible timeout value
}
$('#men, #ddmen').addEventListener('onmouseover', stopMenuTimeoutAndShowMenu);
$('#men, #ddmen').addEventListener('onmouseout', startMenuTimeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try simple CSS changes, that can even help you :

In your Style.css file:

```
    .dropdown .dropdowncontent {
      visibility: hidden;
     }
    .dropdown:hover .dropdowncontent {
      visibility: visible;
     }
```